# How to make NavBar with just Angular Material?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, angular, angular-material

I'm trying to use only Angular Material on this project. I don't want any Bootstrap. How can I get a nice nav bar, similar to the one on the Angular Material website. https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

I've implemented the `MatMenuModule / <mat-menu>` component into my project, but that's not really what I want.

Also, I am correct in thinking I shouldn't mix Bootstrap with Angular Material? I actually did that prior, and thought it would be better/cleaner/simpler with just Material.

Thanks

Comment: use flexbox with material